# Using PayPal Integration Wizard: Problems with empty variables

Tags: php, paypal

What I have to do:

Client defines a quite tricky product.

Price is calculated according to different Parameters via javascript.
Client states, that he wants to pay with PayPal and sends form.

When checking the content of the form, I want to react on his wish to pay via PayPal.

I used the integration wizard. I implemented paypals expresscheckout.php and paypalfunctions.php.
I set the variables at the start of paypalfunctions.php (sandbox). Made the rest of the code as given and tracked it until the paypal-call.

There is a call to PayPal in their own function "hash_call", where they use these variables.
But they are empty.

code in paypalfunctions.php

```
Defines all the global variables and the wrapper functions 
********************************************/
$PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$PROXY_PORT = '808';

$SandboxFlag = true;

//'------------------------------------
//' PayPal API Credentials
//' Replace <API_USERNAME> with your API Username
//' Replace <API_PASSWORD> with your API Password
//' Replace <API_SIGNATURE> with your Signature
//'------------------------------------

$API_UserName="myemail";
$API_Password="mypw";
$API_Signature="mysignature";
```

...

code in hash_call: The function hash_call ist part of paypalfunctions.php

function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)

{

...

//declaring of global variables

global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;

...

Whats going wrong?

There is a link zu the wizard: https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php

Piet

Comment: `global` simply pulls the variable from the global scope. I don't see you define `$API_Endpoint` and `$version` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using the wrong API Credentials.
I noticed in your example you put the following:

```
$API_UserName="myemail";
$API_Password="mypw";
$API_Signature="mysignature";
```

Just to be clear your API User name is not your Email address. Your API Password is not your PayPal Password.
Just in case you need it, here is an example of what API credentials look like and how to request them from your PayPal Account. You can use these same instructions on your Sandbox account as well:
[API Credential Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/)
Also make certain of your endpoint. The endpoint is where you are pointing your customers. Are you pointing them at the live site or the sandbox site?
Just in case you need them, here is the API endpoint information:
[PayPal API Endpoint Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/)

Make certain that if you are using Sandbox Credentials you are using Sandbox endpoints, and if you are using live credentials, make certain to use the live endpoint.